# Batch file variables are not properly initialized on startup

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that sets a variable and then runs a python script:

```
@echo off
SET TOKEN=111222333

python D:\Scripts\my_script.py


cmd /k
```

In my Python script I refer to this variable as follows:

```
import os


token = str(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
bot = Bot(token=token)
```

My batch file is placed in the Startup folder, so it runs every time the system loads. But when the batch file runs automatically, I get a following error:

```
ValidationError: Token is invalid!
```

When I restart the batch file manually, everything works fine. I suppose that batch file variables aren't properly initialized on startup.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Set` defines a variable for the local cmd.exe instance. When you try to retrieve it from the environment in another cmd.exe isntance it will not exist there. The simplest way to do this is to pass the variable as an argument to the python script, and in that script `import sys`, and use `sys.argv[1]` to reference the received argument.

Comment: If you want a variable to be available in all cmd.exe instances, you'd need to define that first in an initial cmd.exe instance, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe TOKEN 111222333`. If you need to reference it in the defining instance as well, you'd need to use both that and `Set TOKEN=111222333`.

Comment: @Compo  unfortunately, it doesn't work with sys.argv[1] either. On startup i get the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. It seems that the problem comes from the order of system loading. Perhaps, some services are not initialized yet, when my script tries to define variables or send arguments. Both variants work fine after manual restart though.